# Encyclopedia of categories

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, category-theory

Is there a digest of the most widely used categories with their basic properties mentioned? So I could, say, learn from it in a couple of minutes that the category with totally ordered sets as objects and monotonic functions as morphisms hasn't got coproducts (unless for some specific cases).

Comment: I think the tag (reference-request) might apply here as well

Comment: Rephrasing Borges, "This cyclical book would be God."

Comment: Almost the same question has been asked here some weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) contains, as an appendix, a substantial table of some commonly used categories, with references to some of their properties in the text.